# Mail function not sending in HTML format

Tags: codeigniter, php

HUGE EDIT!!!!!!!!!
Ok, so it's not the HTML or whatever. When I paste it raw in the PHP message variable, it sends perfectly formatted. It's something with the textarea box paste part... that's making it not work properly. Is it the newline thing?.... Hmmmmm

Ok so this has been a frustrating day for me. I'm trying to send HTML emails where I can paste it in the message form textarea. Well I stripped it down to the barebones and it will NOT let anything above the body and after the body be put into HTML.

It prints this:

```
<html> <head> <title>HalfOffDeals - Thank you!</title> </head> <body>
```

Then it spits out the body... although unformatted with no style.

Then this afterwards:

```
</body> </html>
```

I tried putting the inline CSS how you're suppose to with the style tag and it just omits that completely. I'm using CodeIgniter and I don't know if it strips it automatically which it shouldn't.. I have a form that says (TO, SUBJECT, and MESSAGE). And in the message part, you paste your HTML email template and it's suppose to send to the to email.

And another question I had was how to add '' to the headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

I'm just confused on why my email isn't accepting HTML. This is how I have it setup:

```
public function send_email() {
    $to = $this->input->post('to');
    $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
    $message .= $this->input->post('message');

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: Customer <'.$to . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: noreply@intellectproductions.com <noreply@intellectproductions.com>' . "\r\n";

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Any ideas?

HERE IS THE EMAIL TEMPLATE: http://pastebin.com/D04cLXe4

Comment: I see that you use `$this->input->post()` so, are you using CodeIgniter? Cause if you are, you can just use the [CI Email class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) setting the appropriate mailtype.

Comment: Yes I am using CodeIgniter. Hmmm lemme see!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $headers .= 'To: Customer <'.$to . "\r\n";
```

change to

```
 $headers .= 'To: Customer <'. $to .'>'."\r\n";
```

and try:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

change to 

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

your server is linux, newline is "\n" if windows "\r\n"

Comment: It still does the same thing. Spits out "<html> <head> <title>HalfOffDeals - Thank you!</title> </head> <body> ", shows the body unformatted, and then spits out the ending "</body> </html> "

Comment: CI [already has code to do this](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Email.php#L1273), I don't think it's good advice to do this in the application. This code is harder to read, hard to get right and therefore hard to maintain -- using the framework abstraction is a much better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are indeed using CodeIgniter -- so, I recommend using [CodeIgniter's Email class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html).

Try changing your function to this:

```
public function send_email() {
    $to = $this->input->post('to');
    $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
    $message .= $this->input->post('message');

    $this->load->library('email');

    // To send HTML mail, set the appropriate mailtype
    $this->email->set_mailtype('html');

    // setup the message
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->from('noreply@intellectproductions.com');
    $this->email->subject('Put the subject here');
    $this->email->message($message);

    // Mail it
    $this->email->send();
}
```

This will do the right thing to handle HTML emails even if they have attachments.
Save your code to what matters, you don't [need to do all this work](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Email.php#L1273). ;)

Comment: When I switch it to using the CI email class, it won't send. I notice it says "from". Does that have to be a valid email address? And do I have to do all the stmp and password and stuff?

Comment: You can configure the default settings for sending email in the `application/config/email.php file`. Check out the section "Setting Email Preferences" in [the class documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html).

Comment: Ok it finally sent. I guess it was taking forever, but it's still not liking anything above the body tag or below it.. See my pastebin for what I'm pasting..

Answer (score 0):

To send `html` in email you can use default CI email settings;

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config = array(
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'newline' => '\r\n',
        'charset' => 'utf-8' //default charset
    );
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from($sender);
    $this->email->to($receiver);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();
```

For more details see [CI email class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html).
Also try to use `$this->email->print_debugger()` to see email errors/

Answer (score 0):

Back when I used the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) mail function, I also ended up with some problems. Then I met the **class phpmailer** and my problems were over. Take a good look at it. It's worth it.